# How can I assign spatial information in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

I am very new to ArcGIS and I hope I have over-looked something obvious with this!

I have a set of polygons that have been loaded into ArcGIS Pro 10.3 without coordinate information. Unfortunately, it is not possible for me to get the co-ordinate information however I have been able to move the polygons to the correct position on a world map (it was quite easy because they line up with roads). However, I am unable now to 'share' this data online because I get the error: '20028 Data source has no spatial reference'.

Please does anybody know a way around this? Is there another way of sharing it or, ideally, can I get ArcGIS to work out the spatial references given the positions of the polygons on the map?

Comment: Related question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159217/how-can-i-move-a-set-of-polygons-in-arcgis-pro

Answer (score 1):

The spatial reference that your error message is referring to is the missing coordinate system that we worked on on your other question ([Moving set of polygons in ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159217/how-can-i-move-a-set-of-polygons-in-arcgis-pro)).

I would recommend trying to figure out the coordinate system first instead of moving the data manually and then trying to apply a coordinate system (spatial reference).  (My reasoning being that the more manipulation you do the data first before trying to assign a correct spatial reference, the more difficult it will be.)

[Identifying Coordinate System of Shapefile when Unknown?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/identifying-coordinate-system-of-shapefile-when-unknown) addresses how to figure out an unknown coordinate system.  I particularly like mkennedy's answer since it has more detail.  It is for working in ArcMap but I imagine ArcGIS Pro works similarly.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks for the link Sara! I can't check it out until after the weekend now but my fingers are crossed!

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply on this. I tried the suggestions on the link but couldn't get it to work on ArcGIS (probably a reflection of my GIS ineptitude rather than the software). I found out, more by accident than anything, that I was able to share the file as a webmap despite having the error and it is appearing correctly online. I did this by not clicking 'analyze' and going straight to 'share' instead. Probably not ideal but a sufficient fix for now!

Comment: @JamieEdgecombe Glad you got it working!